# Trying to apply Solow model to the US econmy

Tags: solow

In a textbook application I try to apply Solow model to the US economy. What will be a ballpark estimate of the saving rate and the depreciation rate?

**Edit:** To follow up, assume Cobb-Douglas with labor share 0.3. Assume Y=16916*10^9 and K-22541*10^9 and L=151.4*10^6. Then A=3*10^3. Then s-0.3 and delta-0.05. Does this seem make sense?

Comment: You tell us, you are the one applying it!

Comment: Penn World Tables has savings and depreciation rates